# why is my website being redirected?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have this .htaccess code mod_rewrite problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

but when i type www.example.com, it redirect me to www.example.com/user.php, it redirect the hompage index.

EDIT: this .htaccess code deos this for me.

it changes the unfriendly url of www.example.com/user.php?user=solomon

to this www.example.com/solomon

but the problem is when i try to go to my homepage, by just typing www.example.com
it thinks im asking for a user, when i just want my homepage!! so i want to avoid that

Comment: it redirects my homepage!!!, which is the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want everything BUT index redirected to /user.php?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^(\/|index.php)](.+)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

This is UNTESTED, but it "should" work. I am not running apache on my local laptop, but I think that's the regex.

Here's the basic idea : you want to match anything that is NOT / or (|) index.php - both of which are the home page. Add more pipes for other pages to directly serve:

```
/|index.php|contact.php|about.php|etc
```

Comment: thanks that works, but the actual user.php=user pages are not being redirected now to example.com/user , so we have switched roles now lool :)) +1 upvote from me

Comment: wait, so you WANT to redirect to /user.php?user=1? See my edit

Comment: Okay, you're question is malformed and doesn't make sense. This is why I'm having trouble answering. you don't say anything about redirecting to user.php

Comment: this code should do what youre asking... i dont understand what its not doing for you

Comment: the first one works, the second one deosnt, it gives you the error, becuase your not passing the user variable!!!

Comment: you have a syntax error in your mysql_fetch_array. it's redirecting correctly. also, please NEVER develop on a live server - google will hate you

Comment: oh okay thanks, i never knew that!!! wow i never knew that, thanks for telling me!!

Comment: Also, I'd be happy to help you with the most important part of your site - A SITEMAP. If you want to go anywhere, you'll need dynamically created sitemap indexes and subsitemaps for each user if you want any SEO

Comment: yeh of course, but im still developing you see, im developing my website using netbeans which sends my work automatically to my server, when save something, is that still BAD!!

Comment: OMG YES! You should develop locally. You are wasting bandwidth on every save too. Why are you using netbeans anyway? Netbeans is a terrible IDE. Use Aptana or Textmate (If you're on a Mac). Real developers don't rely on code-hinting and autocomplete. Install PHP, Apache, and MySQL on your local machine and develop there. You have three environments with coding - development, testing, and production...

Comment: oh okay thanks, but im  on windows, and how do i transfer my files!

Comment: first, you want to install WAMP - windows apache mysql and php - its free. Then, download Aptana. Then, check your stuff into version control - i prefer git on github (its well worth the 9$ a month). then, you can revert to earlier versions of your code. Then, youll want to pull your site down until it's ready for beta testing. use ftp to put to your server